# The thickness of a puddled sheet of water

Tags: water, fluid-statics

If I pour water of different amounts into a puddle on a level surface, it appears by eye that both puddles have the same height. The water seems to retain itself into a puddle by surface tension. I have two questions:

(1) Does the height of a puddle of water on an infinite level surface depend on the material out of which the surface is made?

(2) Does the height of the puddle vary depending on how much water is in the puddle?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension#Puddles_on_a_surface should answer that.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the page linked in the comments, the answer seems to be the following:

(1) The height of the puddle does not depend on the material of the surface so long as the surface is nonwetting.

(2) If the amount of water is large then it makes no difference, but if the amount is small, such as a droplet, then the contact angle will become significant and the height will depend on the contact angle.